# Why does Windows Authentication fail when using Windows Azure Emulator?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-authentication, azure-cloud-services

I created a `Cloud Service` project containing an `MVC Application` in a `Web Role`, and a `Worker Role`.  In the MVC project, I am using `Windows Authentication`...and certain fields are managed based on the user being authorized (no biggie).

When I "Set As Startup Project" to the MVC project, my `Windows Identity Principal` comes across fine...and everything displays & works as expected (which is good).

Then, it becomes time to work-on & debug the `Worker Role`.  To do so, I must run the `Windows Azure Emulator` by choosing "Set As Startup Project" to the `Cloud Service` project itself (and then pressing F5).  Doing so fires-up all the `Cloud Service` roles within the `Windows Azure Emulator`.

However, when I do this the `IsAuthenticated` property is false...and all my HTML elements disappear.

**QUESTION(S):**
 - Why does running the `Windows Azure Emulator` locally prevent `Windows Authentication`?
 - If I need to "setup" the emulator...how?

---

**PORTION OF THE SERCURITY CODE:**
Nothing special here...

```
var identity = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
   RedirectToAccessDeniedPage(filterContext);
```

**PORTION OF THE WEB CONFIG:**
Nothing special here...

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

Comment: that is probably because windows azure emulator is a virtual machine and hence your windows auth wont work there. Unless you somehow set it up manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup the MVC project as the startup project, you are essentially running the project locally on your machine through IIS. IIS will automatically use your current NT credentials as the currently logged in user, which makes sense.

As hinted by Parv Sharma in his comment, when you set the cloud service as the startup project, a separate VM emualtor is started, simulating what would happen in the cloud. Although the VM also runs your application in IIS, it has no idea who you are since you haven't logged in yet. And because your local NT credentials are not stored in that VM (and it doesn't make sense to store user credentials in a VM regardless), IIS doesn't recognize you as being logged in.

So you will need to implement a form of authentication form that will allow users to authenticate against a Directory Store, which is what Azure Directory Services is all about. Here is the MSDN documentation for [Azure Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn499820.aspx) scenarios which contains a link for a sample implementation.